# is it possible to make RNN using FANN

Tags: php, fann

Im playing with PHP-CLI and MQL4. I want to create a neural network for FOREX predictions.

Is it possible to make a recurrent neural network (RNN) with gated recurring units (GRU) or long short-term memory (LTSM) using FANN library?

Answer (score 1):

No, FANN does not support [recurrent neural networks (GRU, LSTM)](http://leenissen.dk/fann/forum/viewtopic.php?t=47).